# Some Ubuntu services are starting even if they are disabled

Tags: bluetooth, services, systemd

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 (budgie desktop), and I disabled the bluetooth service to prevent the bluetooth from being enabled with the computer startup. I used this command to disable it :

```
sudo systemctl disable bluetooth.service
```

And I used this command to confirm that it is disabled :

```
systemctl is-enabled bluetooth.service
> disabled
```

But sometimes, the bluetooth (and some other services) are starting with the computer even if they are disabled. Is it a bug ? or am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe some other service or socket needs them thus starts them at the point of need. You should mask the service if you don't want it to be started in any way (Automatically, manually or by any other service) :

```
sudo systemctl mask name.service
sudo systemctl stop name.service
sudo systemctl disable name.service
```

Masking a service points it to `/dev/null` so it's not going to be enabled/started anymore.

If you want to enable it again use:

```
sudo systemctl unmask name.service
sudo systemctl enable name.service
```

To find out which services are depends on a specific service you can use something like:

```
grep -Ri name.service /lib/systemd/system
```

e.g:

```
$ grep -Ri bluetooth.service /lib/systemd/system
./tlp.service:Wants=bluetooth.service NetworkManager.service
```

we can see in my Ubuntu `tlp` service needs bluetooth and NetworkManager.

A better option is to use:

```
$ systemctl list-dependencies bluetooth.service --reverse 

bluetooth.service
● └─tlp.service
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful informations. Is there a way to know which service is starting my disabled services (since they didn't start automatically).

Comment: I've done another update, it might be helpful to notice ;)

Comment: This is epic, the second approach is even better. Thanks.